# Is it necessary ''to''?

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, indirect-objects

Because Delhi has almost 20 million inhabitants, **to** make it sustainable is a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Without *to*, *make*, not having a subject, has to be read as an imperative verb, but then the subsequent *is* doesn't make sense.

The subject of the main clause is *to make it sustainable*. An alternative would be *making it sustainable*: the meaning is hardly any different, but perhaps the use of the infinitive *to make* suggests more purposefulness.